# How to check whether user logged in or not in today using MySQL query

Tags: mysql, select, date-difference

I have table like this; I captured every thing:

id, username, email, last_login

I want to know if user has logged in today or not. Please help me in single query

Comment: first try and then post problem. we are not here to make a code for you.

Comment: have you tried any thing?

Comment: Write an update query to update ' last_login' at the time of user login

Answer (score 0):

First fire update query to update 'last_login' at every user login time, then try this query:

```
$query = "SELECT id, username, email, last_login FROM tbl_name WHERE last_login = NOW()";
```

if this query returns 1 that means user have logged in today into the system, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update 'last_login' at every user login and to check if a user logged in use this query:

```
SELECT id, username, email, last_login FROM tbl_name WHERE CONVERT(date,last_login) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
```

If you want just checking and return a bool you can use this query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(date,last_login) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Yes i want to return type bool value, I checked user logid or not in every night 11:50 PM

Comment: then use the second one

Answer (score 0):

Try with this before going with this ensure that the login user has to update his last login

```
select id, username, email, last_login from table_name  where last_login=now()
```